# In WinUI 3 and C#, how do I bind to the auto-generated CheckBox controls from a ListView that has the property selectionMode="Multiple"?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, winui-3, winui

I have the following XAML code that binds to an object to populate a ListView in WinUI 3 with C#:

```
<ListView x:Name="filterListView" selectionMode="Multiple" 
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SubFilterName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

This code creates a list of checkboxes to the left of the text for each item in this `ListView`. But there is no `CheckBox` control for me to bind to... it's created automatically using the `selectionMode="Multiple"` property.

**So the question is, how do I bind my `bool` `IsSelected` property to the auto-generated `CheckBox` created by `filterListView` in the code above?**

An answer either within the XAML or C# code-behind is fine. As long as I can get it working.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there's no straight way to do this. You can bind those `CheckBoxes` like this:

```cs
// FindDescendants() comes from CommuityToolkit.WinUI.UI NuGet package.
foreach (ListViewItem listViewItem in this.filterListView
    .FindDescendants()
    .OfType<ListViewItem>())
{
    if (listViewItem.Content is not SubFilter subFilter)
    {
        continue;
    }

    listViewItem.SetBinding(
        ListViewItem.IsSelectedProperty,
        new Binding()
        {
            Source = subFilter,
            Path = new PropertyPath("IsSelected"),
            Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
            UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
        });
}
```

But I would set `SelectionMode` to `None` and add a `CheckBox` in the `DataTemplate`.